Ubuntu 24.04 remove all icons from desktop?
I recently upgraded one pc from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04, and performed a full install of 24.04 on a second pc. I have always kept my desktop free from all icons. Now, both desktops are cluttered with all files and folders from my Desktop folder. How do I get rid of all those icons? I don't want to go back to 22.04 but will if that's what it takes to have a clutter free desktop. Please help. I should mention that the 2 pcs are networked. Probably not the cause but prior to 24.04 they were not networked.

Install the GNOME Shell Extension manager with
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-prefs

Then, disable the extension for showing desktop icons.

That did it! Thank you so very much. My desktop is now back to being completely uncluttered (except for t!he dock). Perfect!

If it works, you can accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark on the left side.

Why isn't this in Gnome Tweaks anymore?

@Natim Only the GNOME developers would know that

You can do it from the CLI:
gnome-extensions disable ding@rastersoft.com

